# sorting and filtering in datagridview where data is from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, linq, stored-procedures, datagridview

my project is in **vbnet**. 
i have a **stored procedure**, and get the results with **linq**. i know how to get it with sql adapter, which is easy in sorting and filtering, but i have to do it with linq.

my code is like that.

```
dgv.DataSource = db.Egitek_Gorev_Listesi(LoggedUserID)
```

data is shown in datagridview, but i can not filter,**search** or **order** in it.

does anybody know a better way todo it.

Comment: Use the [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for encapsulating your datasource and set the binding source as your DataGridView's datasource. You can do filter, sort on the BindingSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
bSource = New BindingSource() 
table = New DataTable 
dgv.DataSource = bSource 
dataAdapter = db.Egitek_Gorev_Listesi(LoggedUserID)
dataAdapter.Fill(table) 
bSource.DataSource = table
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a binding source and assign the datasource of this binding source as the the dataset that you get from the database.
Use this binding source as a datasource of the datagridview.

Comment: this is just an example

        Dim bs As New BindingSource
        bs.DataSource = db.Egitek_Gorev_Listesi(LoggedUserID)
        dgv.DataSource = bs
        bs.Filter = "ListID = 205"
        bs.Sort = "ListID"

Comment: it doesn't work. bindingsource.filter and bindingsource.sort seems working, but datagridview doesn't refresh after sort or filter